# cannot render image after sending to SQL database from Android

Tags: android, sql, web-services, ksoap

I have an Android application (API 10) that as one of the features allows the user to capture a photo and send it to an asp.net web service using ksoap.  The Android app works fine, sends all data including the image byte array to the database.  The SQL database has an Image field for the data where the byte array is stored.  This all works as expected.  However, when testing to make sure nothing got corrupted, the image saved properly, etc., I try to render the image using an .ashx page and it just displays the "broken image" icon.  I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing, but after staring at it for a long time, it's not making sense.

Here's the snippet of the Android app that grabs the byte array:

```
byte[] ba;
String filepath = "/sdcard/";
File imagefile = new File(filepath + "img.jpg");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imagefile);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
Bitmap sbm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 640, 480, false);
if(bm != null)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    sbm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    ba = out.toByteArray();
}
```

Here's the snippet of the Android app that creates the SOAP and executes it:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, SEND_METHOD_NAME);
request.addProperty("pkid", pkid);
request.addProperty("img", ba);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
MarshalBase64 marshal = new MarshalBase64();
marshal.register(envelope);
AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(SEND_URL);
try
{
    androidHttpTransport.call(SEND_SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And here's the snippet from the ASP.Net web service receiving the SOAP message:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.domain.com")]
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentService(RoutingStyle = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServiceRoutingStyle.RequestElement)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class sendWorkOrderService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["main"].ConnectionString);

    [WebMethod(Description = "This is it", EnableSession = false)]
    public void receive(int pkid, byte[] img)
    {
        if (img.Length > 0)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("update table set photo = @arrayToInsert where pkid = " + pkid, con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@arrayToInsert", SqlDbType.Image, 16).Value = img;
        }
        else
        {
            // do nothing
        }
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

This app already uses this and another service successfully, the only issue is in the submission of the image file as a byte array, which functions, but I cannot render the image in a test to make sure it sent ok.  I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing.  I appreciate your feedback...

Answer (score 2):

I got it working, the Android code was working properly, the issue was in the service and my test web page.  The service needed to handle the incoming byte array as a SQL parameter for the update statement, like so:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@arrayToInsert", SqlDbType.Image, img.Length).Value = img;
```

where "img" is the incoming byte array from Android.  Then in the test web page, I rendered the image like so:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select photo from table where pkid = @ImageID", con);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageID", Request.QueryString["ImageID"]);
byte[] image = (byte[])command.ExecuteScalar();
stream.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
System.Drawing.Image bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
bitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
con.Close();
stream.Close();
```

That's all it needed!  Thanks to [@andrewr73](https://twitter.com/#!/AndrewR73) for the advice!